# HTTP post method gives an error when compiling with Angular 6 and Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have created an Angular project to add data to the Neo 4j database. I have accomplished the basic tasks using Angular 6 and TypeScript. But there is a problem when the compilation occurs. In the first time when I try to serve the application using 'ng serve' command, it will give the following error and say 'compilation failed'.

```
'ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(274,26): error TS2554: Expected 0-2 arguments, but got 4.
src/app/app.component.ts(339,26): error TS2554: Expected 0-2 arguments, but got 3.'
```

But when I erase a letter in a comment or do any other change in a comment, it will recompile real time and even though it gives the above error message it will compile successfully. But the problem is I want to build the app using 'ng build' to deploy it in a server. When I try to build this it will always fail, giving the above error message.

Following is a screenshot of the issue.
[image]

Here are my imports,

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import APP_CONFIG from './app.config';
import {Node, Link} from './d3';
import {NEODictionary} from './d3/models/dictionary';
import {Http, RequestOptions, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/index';
```

Here is my constructor,

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.ontologyDropdown = 'All';
        this.relSourceDropdown = 'select';
        this.relDirectionDropdown = 'nodirection';
        this.relDestinationDropdown = 'select';
        this.setJsonData('All');

        this.onEditCloseItems();
        this.fieldArray.push({name: 'name', value: ''});
    }
```

Here is my code,

```
async addNodeToDB() {
        if ((this.nodeLabel == null) || (this.nodeLabel  === '' )) {
            alert('Please insert a Node Label!')
        } else if (this.fieldArray.length === 0) {
            alert('Please insert the name of the node!')
        } else if (this.fieldArray[0].value === '') {
            alert('Please insert the name of the node!')
        } else {
            const node_properties = [];
            const node_info = {};

            for (let i = 0; i < this.fieldArray.length; i++) {
                const node_prop = {'prop_name': this.fieldArray[i]['name'], 'prop_value': this.fieldArray[i]['value']};
                node_properties.push(node_prop)
            }
            const postbody = {
                'nodeInfo': {
                    'name': this.nodeLabel,
                    'properties': node_properties
                }
            };
            console.log(postbody);
            const addNodeUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/ontology/node_info';
            const headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            //This is the line referred to as (274,26) in error message
            return await this.http.post(addNodeUrl, postbody, {headers: headers}).toPromise()
                .then(this.getDomainDatabase(this.nodeLabel),
                    this.setDropDownNodes(this.ontologyDropdown),
                    // AppComponent.extractData,
                    alert('Node added successfully!!!'),
                    this.clearPropertyList())
                .catch();
        }
    }




async addRelationshipToDB() {
        if (this.relSourceDropdown === 'select') {
            alert('Please select a source node!');
        } else if ((this.relType == null) || this.relType === '') {
            alert('Please insert the relationship type!');
        } else if (this.relDirectionDropdown === 'nodirection') {
            alert('Please select a relationship direction!');
        } else if (this.relDestinationDropdown === 'select') {
            alert('Please select a destination node!');
        } else {
            const rel_properties = [];
            const rel_info = {};

            for (let i = 0; i < this.fieldArrayRel.length; i++) {
                const rel_prop = {
                    'prop_name': this.fieldArrayRel[i]['name'],
                    'prop_value': this.fieldArrayRel[i]['value']
                };
                rel_properties.push(rel_prop)
            }
            const postbody = {
                'relationshipInfo': {
                    'rel_name': this.relType,
                    'source': {
                        'name': this.nodeLabel,
                        'properties': [{
                            'prop_name': 'name',
                            'prop_value': this.relSourceDropdown
                        }]
                    },
                    'destination': {
                        'name': this.nodeLabel,
                        'properties': [{
                            'prop_name': 'name',
                            'prop_value': this.relDestinationDropdown
                        }]
                    },
                    'rel_properties': rel_properties,
                    'direction': this.relDirectionDropdown
                }
            };
            const addRelUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/ontology/rel_info';
            const headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            //This is the line referred to as (339,26) in error message
            return await this.http.post(addRelUrl, postbody, {headers: headers}).toPromise()
                .then(this.getDomainDatabase(this.nodeLabel),
                    // AppComponent.extractData,
                    alert('Relationship added successfully'),
                    this.clearRelForm())
                .catch();
        }
    }
```

However, I tried removing the {headers: headers} argument also in both places but it still gave the same error. The app works fine but I can't build it because of this issue.

Comment: `.post(addRelUrl, postbody, {headers: headers})` expected 2 arguments, got 3. Press "go to definition" on the post method, see where the type declaration is loaded from.

Comment: @c69 I already did it. It's as follows.                                                                 
 post(url: string, body: any | null, options?: {
        headers?: HttpHeaders | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
        };
        observe?: 'body';
        params?: HttpParams | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
        };
        reportProgress?: boolean;
        responseType?: 'json';
        withCredentials?: boolean;
    }): Observable<Object>;    What am i missing?

Comment: weird... is the problem only on your machine ? have you tried clean checkout / npm install (in other folder) ?

Comment: @c69 I think I figured out where the problem is. Have you noticed that in addNodeToDB() method after post there is .then(this.getDomainDatabase(this.nodeLabel),
                    this.setDropDownNodes(this.ontologyDropdown),
                    // AppComponent.extractData,
                    alert('Node added successfully!!!'),
                    this.clearPropertyList()) with 4 method calls and at the same place in adding relationship method there is 3. Can u suggest a way to solve that problem.

Comment: I have tried adding those methods in to two seperate methods and calling those two methods. But now it gives the following error.                              error TS2345: Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => Object | PromiseLike<Object>'.
src/app/app.component.ts(355,23): error TS2345: Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => Object | PromiseLike<Object>'

Comment: I figured out the solution myself. All I had to do was to remove all the methods from '.then()' and make a separate method for each of the two methods 'addNodeToDB' and 'addRelationshipToDB' and call these methods in that newly created methods. That solved the problem.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.